# Integrating firebase analytics with react.js node web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to add firebase analytics to my react.js node app, but keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Object(*firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["areCookiesEnabled"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(*firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["areCookiesEnabled"])()', 'Object(*firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_["areCookiesEnabled"])' is an instance of Object)

I import firebase, initialize firebase, and then try to initialize analytics:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: '',
     authDomain: '',
     databaseURL: '',
     projectId: '',
     storageBucket: '',
     messagingSenderId: '',
     appId: '',
     measuremendId: ''
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
var db = firebase.firestore()
var analytics = firebase.analytics()
```

In my package.json file:

```
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.20.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.7.1",
```

Weirdly, it did build and deploy without errors once, but when I revert to that commit I still get the error even with the original working code. Is there something wrong with my configuration, or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import Firebase Analytics

```
import 'firebase/analytics'
```